# Using enumerate() and takewhile() to return a list in python

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools

I'm trying to define a method to return a list of the first n elements of a Fibonacci generator using enumerate() and takewhile(). My code goes into an infinite loop and never checks the condition in takewhile() to stop iterating. I know islice() is much easier, but I need to define the method using only enumerate and takewhile.

```
from itertools import takewhile


def fibonacci_unbounded():
    (a, b) = (0, 1)
    while True:
        yield a
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)


def take_e(n, gen):
    fib_list = []
    for (i, elem) in enumerate(gen):
        if takewhile(i < n, gen):
            fib_list.append(elem)
        else:
            return fib_list


fibonacci = fibonacci_unbounded
n = 8

print(take_e(n, fibonacci()))
```

Comment: what are you doing with `if takewhile(i < n, gen):`??? That doesn't make any sense. I think you want `list(takewhile(lambda i_e: i_e[0] < n, fibonacci_unbounded()))`

Comment: I think you mean "return a list" rather than "return a list comprehension", yes?  Although it might be possible to return a comprehension, much like returning a function reference, that's not a usual thing.  Do you mean "return a list created by a list comprehension"? - or maybe you don't want anything to do with a list comprehension.  I don't see one in your code.

Comment: enumerate() returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable. So, I'm trying to use that count in enumerate as i to check my condition, hence `if takewhile(i < n, gen)`. I'm new to Python, not sure if I can do that or not.

Comment: Yes, I meant to say return a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` works much like `enumerate` when you use a `range` iterator. The nice part is that `zip` stops on the shortest iteration. So ditch `takewhile` and use an enumerator that stops at the right place.

```
def fibonacci_unbounded():
    (a, b) = (0, 1)
    while True:
        yield a
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)

def take_e(n, gen):
    return list((elem) for _,elem in zip(range(n), gen))

fibonacci = fibonacci_unbounded
n = 8
print(take_e(n, fibonacci()))
```

If using `takewhile` and `enumerate` is a requirement, you should take values from the enumeration until the condition is met.

```
from itertools import takewhile

def fibonacci_unbounded():
    (a, b) = (0, 1)
    while True:
        yield a
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)

def take_e(n, gen):
    return list(val for _,val in takewhile(
        lambda i_val: i_val[0] < n, enumerate(gen)))

fibonacci = fibonacci_unbounded
n = 8
print(take_e(n, fibonacci()))
```

Comment: I think the point is that he need to use `takewhile` to stop the iteration.  I've been going on that assumption, per his problem statement.

Comment: Yes, both `takewhile` and `enumerate`

Comment: @Steve - Looks like yours now!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that works.  I was hoping to find a way to not need to add the index into the logic so that you can test for the "nth" item returned:

```
def fibonacci_unbounded():
    (a, b) = (0, 1)
    while True:
        yield a
        (a, b) = (b, a + b)

def take_e(n, gen):
    return [x[1] for x in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] < n, enumerate(gen()))]

print(take_e(9, fibonacci_unbounded))
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21]
```

It would be simpler if I didn't have to use the `takewhile`.  I've never used it before, so I'm not aware if there are special tricks to using it.  It would be easier to just pass the count you desire into the base fibonacci generator and have it stop at the appropriate moment.

Comment: Yea, changing the Fibonacci generator would fix the problem, but the issue is I have 3 other methods that get the first n elements of Fibonacci using different functions and can't change the generator.

Comment: @Ashkan - Ok, here's the same thing, but with the index added via another generator so that the base function doesn't need to change...or is adding a second generator illegal too?

Comment: I think the idea is to use `enumerate` that counts the items and use that count variable as a condition in `takewhile` to stop iterating. That way there's no need to change the generator or add a new one.

Comment: Got it! Your code put me on the right track! Thank you

Comment: ```return [x[1] for x in takewhile(lambda x: x[0] < n, enumerate(gen))]```

Comment: yikes!  enumerate!  I knew I was forgetting something :)